# Cuda to make Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c++, c, cuda, parallel-processing

have a problem making a Matrix Multiplication using cuda. I have to do A*A*A*A and save it in hB. With Cublas it's ok, but I can't make it with CUDA. Dimension can be a high value like 2000. This is my code:

```
__global__ void CudaMM(float *A, float *B, int N)
{

    int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    float sum = 0.f;
    for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        sum += A[row*N+n]*A[n*N+col];

    B[row*N+col] = sum;
}

void CudaMult(int dimension,float *hMatrice,float *hB,float *d_A,float *d_B){
    int N,K;
    K = 100;            
    N = K*BLOCK_SIZE;

    dim3 threadBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 grid(K,K);

    cudaMemcpy(d_A,hMatrice,dimension*dimension*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

CudaMM<<<grid,threadBlock>>>(d_A,d_B,N);

cudaMemcpy(hB,d_B,dimension*dimension*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


}

void CublasFindConnect(int dimension,float* mat,float* B){


    float *d_A,*d_B;
    cudaMalloc(&d_A,dimension*dimension*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&d_B,dimension*dimension*sizeof(float));

    int w=0;
    while(w<5){

        CudaMult(dimension,mat,B,d_A,d_B);

          // Copy Matrix computed B to previous M

            for (m=0; m<dimension; m++) {

                for (n=0; n<dimension; n++) {
                    mat[m*dimension+n]=B[m*dimension+n];
                    B[m*dimension+n]=0;
                }
            }

     w++;
    }

cudaFree(d_A);
cudaFree(d_B);

}
```

I've installed last CUDA 6 that it doesn't require cudaMemCpy, because memory is shared.

Comment: Do you do [proper error checking for your CUDA program](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14038589/2386951)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I would suggest you start by doing proper [cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) on the code you have shown, and see what results you get.
- It will be better if you show a *complete* code as well.  For example what is `BLOCK_SIZE`?  The idea is not to tell me what `BLOCK_SIZE` is, but to show a *complete* code.
- As an aside, the feature you are referring to in CUDA 6 has specific requirements (such as the use of `cudaMallocManaged()`) that you're not meeting, but nevertheless your code is not dependent on Unified Memory, so it's irrelevant.

One problem I can see in your code is that your `dimension` variable is arbitrary (you say it can be up to a large number like 2000) but your computation size is fixed at `N=K*BLOCK_SIZE;`.  Presumably if your BLOCK_SIZE is some value like 16 or 32, then it will meet your approximate max `dimension` size of ~2000.

The problem arises because your grid size is potentially larger than your valid array size.  You are launching an `N`x`N` grid, but `N` can be larger than `dimension`.  This means some of the launched threads can attempt to access the matrices (`A` and `B`) outside of their valid dimensions.

You can fix this with a "thread check" in your kernel, something like this:

```
__global__ void CudaMM(float *A, float *B, int N)
{

    int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if ((row < N) && (col < N)) {

      float sum = 0.f;
      for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        sum += A[row*N+n]*A[n*N+col];

      B[row*N+col] = sum;
    }
}
```

and you will need to modify your kernel invocation to:

```
CudaMM<<<grid,threadBlock>>>(d_A,d_B,dimension);
```

You might also want to consider choosing grid sizes based on your actual `dimension`, rather than fixed at `100*BLOCK_SIZE`, but that is not essential to get the code to work.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question. Why Cublas Multiplication is faster than CUDA?

Comment: CUBLAS uses CUDA, but it's highly optimized code, written by experts.  Your question is analogous to asking why is MKL faster at doing matrix multiply than a matrix multiply routine that I have written myself.  Your matrix multiply CUDA code is quite naive, and there are basic optimizations you could take advantage of that would make it faster.  If you search on cuda matrix multiply in the search box in the upper right hand corner of this page, you'll find many examples of various optimizations.  The most direct one is to use shared memory in a tiled arrangement.